# How to execute a prefect Flow on a docker image?

Tags: docker, etl, dask, docker-image, prefect

**My goal:**

I have a built docker image and want to run all my Flows on that image.

**Currently:**

I have the following task which is running on a Local Dask Executor.
The server on which the agent is running is a different python environment from the one needed to execute `my_task` - hence the need to run inside a pre-build image.

**My question is:** *How do I run this Flow on a Dask Executor such that it runs on the docker image I provide (as environment)?*

```
import prefect
from prefect import task, Flow
from prefect.engine.executors import LocalDaskExecutor
from prefect.environments import LocalEnvironment


@task
def hello_task():
    logger = prefect.context.get("logger")
    logger.info("Hello, Docker!")


with Flow("My Flow") as flow:
    results = hello_task()

flow.environment = LocalEnvironment(
    labels=[], executor=LocalDaskExecutor(scheduler="threads", num_workers=2),
)
```

I thought that I need to start the server and the agent on that docker image first (as discussed [here](https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/discussions/3449#discussioncomment-92228)), but I guess there can be a way to simply run the Flow on a provided image.

**Update 1**

Following [this](https://docs.prefect.io/orchestration/tutorial/docker.html#persisting-your-flow-with-docker-storage) tutorial, I tried the following:

```
import prefect
from prefect import task, Flow
from prefect.engine.executors import LocalDaskExecutor
from prefect.environments import LocalEnvironment
from prefect.environments.storage import Docker


@task
def hello_task():
    logger = prefect.context.get("logger")
    logger.info("Hello, Docker!")


with Flow("My Flow") as flow:
    results = hello_task()

flow.storage = Docker(registry_url='registry.gitlab.com/my-repo/image-library')
flow.environment = LocalEnvironment(
    labels=[], executor=LocalDaskExecutor(scheduler="threads", num_workers=2),
)

flow.register(project_name="testing")
```

But this created an image which it then uploaded to the `registry_url` provided. Afterwards when I tried to run the registered task, it pulled the newly created image and the task is stuck in status `Submitted for execution` for minutes now.

I don't understand why it pushed an image and then pulled it? Instead I already have an image build on this registry, I'd like to specify an image which should be used for task execution.

Comment: The docs explain this in detail, e.g., [here is a short tutorial](https://docs.prefect.io/orchestration/tutorial/docker.html).  If you are running Prefect Server yourself, you'll need to make sure that the Docker container has network access to your Server API.

Comment: I read this, but it mentions that the `registry_url` is for pushing to a registry (which I find confusing).  "If you do specify a registry URL then the image will be pushed to a container registry upon flow registration."
Is the `registry_url` the url of my image essentially (the one I would like to run)?

Comment: Docker images are typically stored in [Docker registries](https://docs.docker.com/registry/introduction/) - if you don't provide a `registry_url`, the built image will be kept locally on the machine on which it was built.

Comment: Yes, i have my images in a registry (GitLab in my case). Why do I need to provide a registry link and not the specific image link?

Comment: Because the image hasn't been built yet; if you want to specify both the image name and tag (instead of using Prefect's defaults), you can do so via the `image_name` and `image_tag` kwargs on `Docker` storage

Comment: I guess I am not following.
I have a built image in a docker register. For example: `registry.gitlab.com/my-repo/image-library:v1.3` Then I want to run my Flow inside this image. 
To do this I usually need pull the image then run it and then execute some command.

I followed the steps in the link you suggested and I don't understand why does it create a new image which is added to my registry and then pull the new image (instead the one I want)?
I will update the question now, for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way i ended up achieve this is as follows:

1. Run `prefect server start` on the server (i.e. not inside docker).
   Apparently docker-compose in docker is not a good idea.
2. Run `prefect agent start` inside the docker image
3. Make sure the flows are accessible by the docker image (i.e. by mounting a shared volume between the image and the server for
   example)

You can see the source of my answer [here](https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/discussions/3449).